# Add value to column data of dataFrame in Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataFrame like this:

```
>>> data = {'Section':['300/18','2‐ 350/24','400/30']}
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(data)
>>> df
     Section
0     300/18
1  2‐ 350/24
2     400/30
```

I want to `add 50` to the value just before `/`. So the new dataFrame will be like this:

```
     Section
0     350/18
1  2‐ 400/24
2     450/30
```

I know we can for loop the column 'Section', then split the string by '/', then add 50 to the former value, then reformat the string and assign to the cell. Assuming it might have hundred thousand rows, I am wondering if there is more efficient method to do it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One approach would be to use [`str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) with the replacement lambda function to substitute the new values:

```
repl =  lambda g: f'{int(g.group(1)) + 50}/'
df['Section'] = df['Section'].str.replace(r'(\d+)/', repl, regex=True)
```

---

```
     Section
0     350/18
1  2‐ 400/24
2     450/30
```

Comment: I was trying to do this using \\1 instead of `g.group(1)`.   Couldn't get it to work.  +1